# Inaccurate character counts with SLComposeViewController (twitter) and TWTweetComposeViewController

Tags: ios, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'm presenting iOS Twitter share sheets (`SLComposeViewController` on iOS 6, `TWTweetComposeViewController` on iOS 5) in my app with user-selected text and a link.  If the text is too long, I truncate it:

```
NSString *text = [self getSelectedText];
NSString *myLink = [self getLink];
SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[controller addURL:[NSURL urlWithString:myLink]];
while (![controller setInitialText:text] && text.length > 10)
{
  text = [text substringToIndex:text.length - 5];
}

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

When I do this, the character count gets messed up.  `setInitialText` returns `YES` before I'm down to the expected length, and the share sheet comes up showing overflow text.  For example,  if the link is 35 characters long, the share sheet accepts a string of length 117 after decrementing a couple of times.  117 + 35 = 152 (12 over), but the share sheet shows 9 over.

Am I using this API wrong, or is there a bug in the character counts?  [This article](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5024) on Twitter's dev site seems to suggest there's an issue, but it's over a year old.

EDIT: The result is the same if I append the link to the end of the text manually instead of using the `addURL` method.

Comment: Is it helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241160/bug-in-twtweetcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Adding myself to the list of people with this problem. Still an issue in Nov 2013. Extremely frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

The `length` method of `NSString` has limitations with composed character sequences which could be affecting your results.

> The number returned includes the individual characters of composed character sequences, so you cannot use this method to determine if a string will be visible when printed or how long it will appear.

Comment: That's annoying.  But the ultimate issue here isn't with the `length` method, it's with the twitter system telling me I can use a string and then saying it's too long.

Comment: that documentation is referring to the physical space...ie pixels taken up by certain text. The actual length is separate